# issue with react drag & drop image ordering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, algorithm, drag-and-drop, react-dnd

My team bought a template and it has the functionality to add multiple images to a product, and it uses react Dnd. When you open the modal that's used for adding a new product it lets you choose a language for your product which will allow you to display the product's title and description in more than 1 language, however, this functionality does not apply to images and I was told to make that work.

We'll be using the languages French (fr) and English (en).
All images are uploaded to Cloudinary and their URL is stored in the DB.

I came up with a lazy way, instead of creating an object in the db like this:

```
 Images: {
 en: ["url1", "url2", "url3"],
 fr: ["url1", "url2", "url3"]
}
```

I made it so that when you add an images while the language option is set to french it appends the string "PHOTO-FR" to the url of that image before uplaoding it to Cloduinary, and later on I can filter those images to display the ones that only include "PHOTO-FR" for french users and vice versa.

The problem I am facing is that when you try to edit a product, you can correctly see the right images according to your language because of the filtering I mentioned above.

But when you try to drag them to change their position in the array it doesn't work since the array includes all the urls both french and english while the user (trying to edit the product ) only sees the ones corresponding to their chosen language, so to the user it's 3 images for example and to the library trying to re-order them it's 6.

Here's the code responsibe for displaying each images and re-ordering them by just dragging one to the side of another.

```
import update from "immutability-helper";
import { useCallback } from "react";
import Card from "./Card";

const Container = ({ setImageUrl, imageUrl, handleRemoveImage, language }) => {
    const moveCard = useCallback(
        (dragIndex, hoverIndex) => {
            setImageUrl((prevCards) =>
                update(prevCards, {
                    $splice: [
                        [dragIndex, 1],
                        [hoverIndex, 0, prevCards[dragIndex]],
                    ],
                })
            );
        },
        [setImageUrl]
    );

    const renderCard = useCallback(
        (card, i) => {
            return (
                <Card
                    key={i + 1}
                    index={i}
                    id={card.id}
                    text={card.text}
                    moveCard={moveCard}
                    image={card}
                    handleRemoveImage={handleRemoveImage}
                />
            );
        },
        [moveCard, handleRemoveImage]
    );
    if (language.includes("fr"))
        return (
            <>
                {imageUrl
                    ?.filter((url) => url.includes("PHOTO-FR"))
                    ?.map((card, i) => renderCard(card, i))}
            </>
        );
    return (
        <>
            {imageUrl
                ?.filter((url) => !url.includes("PHOTO-FR"))
                .map((card, i) => renderCard(card, i))}
        </>
    );
};

export default Container;
```